# Intermittent Room CursorWindowAllocationException on query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have a simple room database with an intermittent bug (with the same dataset), sometimes when running the first query on the database it will crash with CursorWindowAllocationException.

This does not always happen, the majority of the time it doesn't crash with the exact same dataset.

The query being ran is:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM history")
LiveData<List<HistoryEntity>> getAllHistoryLiveData();
```

Exception:

```
android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. 
    at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:108)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:138)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:132)
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:220)
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:259)
    at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.hasRoomMasterTable(RoomOpenHelper.java:156)
    at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.checkIdentity(RoomOpenHelper.java:124)
    at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onOpen(RoomOpenHelper.java:116)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onOpen(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:151)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:349)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:238)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:96)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:54)
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:238)
    at uk.co.flakeynetworks.HistoryDao_Impl$7.compute(HistoryDao_Impl.java:416)
    at uk.co.flakeynetworks.HistoryDao_Impl$7.compute(HistoryDao_Impl.java:402)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$2.run(ComputableLiveData.java:101)
```

Comment: In the end, the issue was a memory leak where resources weren't being closed properly such as network connections and open streams. This used use too many file descriptors causing the above issue.

Answer (score 1):

CursorWindow in Android is a buffer of database rows that total to a size of 2MB which is 2048kB.

The exception thrown indicates that your process has already reached its allocated memory limit and is hence unable to use or consume an additional 2MB of memory.

You could do the following to fix the issue.

1. Use a paging library to obtain chunks of your data rather than the entire table's data.
2. Recheck your code to see if there are any memory leaks leading to the consumption of your process's memory

[Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/large-database-queries-on-android-cb043ae626e8&ved=2ahUKEwjQlsnqiuPiAhUv6XMBHaAhCt8QjjgwAnoECAcQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3BesXabiFc1_Vahemth7J3&cshid=1560314644803) is a good medium article with detailed explanation of performing large database queries on Android

Comment: Thanks @raxerz, it's a bit confusing because the database only has one row and it definitely isn't anywhere close to 2MB in size so I'm not sure how pages will help. I'll do some checking for other memory leaks

Comment: @Richard Stokes 
This doesn't necessarily mean number of rows, even a large amount of data like a string literal or a blob in a single row that is possibly exceeding the process's memory limit and not just the 2MB of cursor window size can cause this.
But yeah it's good to fix the memory leaks if there are any

Comment: My guess is the row contains 0.5KB of data max

Comment: "Use a paging library to obtain chunks of your data rather than the entire table's data"- A cursor window is already a paged data structure. If it wasn't you could never execute a query that returned >2MB of data.